# How to change connection lost meesage?

Tags: vaadin

When connection with server is lost a "Connection lost, trying to reconnect..." message is shown at top of the page with loading animation, by default. How to change the message to custom one (globally or per page) ?

Vaadin 24 with spring-boot 3.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configruation is done with
[ReconnectDialogConfiguration](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/current/com/vaadin/flow/component/ReconnectDialogConfiguration.html)

This is part of the UI state tree and can be accessed via
[UI::getReconnectDialogConfiguration](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/current/com/vaadin/flow/component/UI.html#getReconnectDialogConfiguration())

So this should be set right in the beginning and this is best done using
the hooks to modify the session setup (e.g. [Service Init
Listener](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/advanced/service-init-listener)).

With Spring this looks like this (register
a `VaadinServiceInitListener`, that registers a `UIInitListener`, that
sets the text):

```
@Bean
VaadinServiceInitListener vaadinServiceInitListener() {
    { serviceInitEvent ->
        serviceInitEvent.source.addUIInitListener { uIInitEvent ->
            uIInitEvent.UI.reconnectDialogConfiguration.dialogText = "Server restart in progress..."
        }
    }
}
```